# How to fix the following error creating a node js class?

Tags: node.js, typescript

Hello I started creating a node.js class as follows:

```
   'use strict';
   let {google} = require('googleapis')
   class Calendar {
       calendarId : string;
```

However, when I test my code I got:

```
      src/utilities/calendar.ts:6
      calendarId : string;
                 ^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
        at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
        at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
        at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
        at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
        at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

So I don't understand why I am getting that, I would like to appreciate suggestions to overcome the issue. My Node version is `8.16.0` and I am also using typescript

Comment: How are you running your code?

Comment: First of all, that's not a javascript syntax. if you are using Typescript, you should compile ts file to javascript first

Comment: I run that as follows: node calendar.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing a typescript file, not a javascript file.

Node cannot automatically run typescript files. You need to:

1. install typecript
2. compile the file
3. run the output with node.js

Alternatively you could use a node like `ts-node` to execute your typescript right from the command-line.